# conversion between Matlab and C++

Tags: c++, matlab, for-loop, type-conversion

I have difficulties while converting the following matlab line into C++:

```
for i=1:height 
  for j=1:width 
    if (match == 0) 
      [min_w, min_w_index] = min(w(i,j,:)); 
      mean(i,j,min_w_index) = double(data(i,j)); 
      sd(i,j,min_w_index) = sd_init; 
    end
    rank = w(i,j,:)./sd(i,j,:); 
    rank_ind = [1:1:C];
  end
end
```

Especially I don't know how to covert the "min_w_index" part. Could someone help me on this point?

Comment: Do you know what matlab is supposed to do with [a,b] = min(...) ?

Comment: yes, it is finding the min value, then assign the min value to "a" I think, and its index to "b". But my question is, I don't know how to convert the "index" part.

Comment: How do you do the first part? (I could provide you with an answer, sure, but I'm sure you're able to figure it out yourself)

Comment: I will get the min value by "for (int k=1;k<Dimension;k++) int min_w = min (w[i][j][k])".

Comment: Well I was writing an answer, but Danil was faster ;-) I agree with him, that's the normal way. Alternatively you can use std::find. the syntax slightly depends on the type of array you're using, so you need to add that to the question if you're interested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most common solution for min function in such case is

```
int min_w = w[i][j][0];
int min_w_index = 0;
for (k = 1; k < maxk; k++)
   if (w[i][j][k] < min_w)
   {
       min_w = w[i][j][k];
       min_w_index = k;
   }
```

Don't forget that C++ has zero-based index, but Matlab one-based. I already see problem in your comment.